# Android ListView inside fragment

Tags: android, listview, layout

Firstly some images:
Need this: [image: need]
Have this: [image: have]
The problem is the blue rectangle. In the first image it does not horizontaly fill whole fragment while in second image it does. Any idea how this could be done?
And of course here is the code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/item_channel.name"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#80161616"
            android:cacheColorHint="#80161616"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/channel_list"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

        <ListView
            style="@style/list"
            android:id="@+id/list_channels"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can't you just add some padding to your ListView?

Comment: It does not work with padding, it only shrinks the whole listview.

Answer (score 0):

You should use adapter to fill your list view. And then you should create another xml for each row. I mean, one xml for earch row. In this xml, you can use margin and padding. And they will effect rows.

Comment: unfortunately it makes something like this ![this](http://i.imgur.com/LCZ70FR.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/item_channel.name"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#80161616"
            android:cacheColorHint="#80161616"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/channel_list"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

        <ListView
            style="@style/list"
            android:id="@+id/list_channels"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then on your listview style:

```
<style name="list" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

I havn't tested the code, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Makes the same image as MSR's answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what you wanted to be done. I edited it, the scrollbar might not look the same.

Comment: Maybe if you take out the padding from the style. If it still doesn't work, then sorry. I'm not sure what's wrong.